# AS3 to Java Game

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash

Im making a java game where there is randomly falling dots all connected toghether making an infinite zigzag. I already did it in AS3 but I am stucked where I need to connect the dots. Here's my AS3 code:

```
package
{
          import flash.display.Graphics;
          import flash.display.MovieClip;
          import flash.display.Sprite;
          import flash.events.Event;
          import flash.events.TimerEvent;
          import flash.utils.Timer;


          public class FallingThings extends Sprite
          {
                    // set width
                    private var w:Number = 0;
                    // set height
                    private var h:Number = 0;
                    private var objectSpawner:Timer;
                    private var fallers:Array;
                    private var speed:Number = 10;
                    public function FallingThings(w:Number, h:Number)


                    {
                              this.w = w;
                              this.h = h;
                              init();
                    }

                    private function init():void
                    {
                              fallers = [];
                              objectSpawner = new Timer(1000);
                              objectSpawner.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, createEnemy);
                              objectSpawner.start();
                              addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dropEnemies);
                    }

                    private function createEnemy(e:TimerEvent):void
                    {
                              var enemy:Faller = new Faller();
                              enemy.y = -h;
                              enemy.x = Math.random() * w;
                              MovieClip(enemy).cacheAsBitmap = true;
                              addChild(enemy);
                              fallers.push(enemy);
                              drawConnectors();


                    }

                    private function dropEnemies(e:Event):void
                    {
                              for each (var mc:Faller in fallers)
                              {
                                        mc.y += speed;
                                        if (mc.y > h * 2)
                                                  fallers.splice(fallers.indexOf(removeChild(mc)), 1);
                              }
                              drawConnectors();
                    }

                    private function drawConnectors():void
                    {
                              if (fallers.length == 0)
                                        return;
                              var g:Graphics = this.graphics;
                              g.clear();
                              g.lineStyle(10,0xFFFFFF);
                              var mc:Faller = fallers[0];
                              g.moveTo(mc.x, mc.y);
                              for each (mc in fallers)
                                        g.lineTo(mc.x, mc.y);
                              import flash.events.Event;


}


                    }

          }
```

Comment: what's the specific question you have?

Comment: To connect all falling dots together like I did in this As3 code

Comment: That much is clear, but do you want to do it in java, as3? you're not very clear on that.

Comment: Oh Im sorry ! Yes in Java